# Generic method decorator typing

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to make `foo` generic decorator to conform `MethodDecorator` type:

```
const foo: MethodDecorator = function <T extends Function = Function>(
    target: object,
    propertyKey: string | symbol,
    descriptor: TypedPropertyDescriptor<T>
): TypedPropertyDescriptor<T> {
    return {
        configurable: true,
        enumerable: false,
        value: descriptor.value!.bind(null)
    };
}
```

`foo` may be used directly as helper function, I would prefer to have an option to additionally type it as a generic.

[Here is](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=const%20foo%3A%20MethodDecorator%20%3D%20function%20%3CT%20extends%20Function%20%3D%20Function%3E(%0D%0A%20%20%20%20target%3A%20object%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20propertyKey%3A%20string%20%7C%20symbol%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20descriptor%3A%20TypedPropertyDescriptor%3CT%3E%0D%0A)%3A%20TypedPropertyDescriptor%3CT%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20return%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20configurable%3A%20true%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20enumerable%3A%20false%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20value%3A%20descriptor.value!.bind(null)%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A) the error:

```
Type '<T extends Function = Function>(target: object, propertyKey: string | symbol, descriptor: TypedPr...' is not assignable to type 'MethodDecorator'.
  Types of parameters 'descriptor' and 'descriptor' are incompatible.
    Type 'TypedPropertyDescriptor<T>' is not assignable to type 'TypedPropertyDescriptor<Function>'.
      Types of property 'value' are incompatible.
        Type 'T | undefined' is not assignable to type 'Function | undefined'.
          Type 'T' is not assignable to type 'Function | undefined'.
            Type 'T' is not assignable to type 'Function'.
```

How can `foo` conform `MethodDecorator`?

Comment: foo is `MethodDecorator ` and the ruturn type of anonymous function is `TypedPropertyDescriptor`.  You can't assign them. I think, it is an open issue. https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/6173

Comment: @RitwickDey Thanks for the reference, good to know. But the issue refers to decorators in general, not to MethodDecorator. MethodDecorator type *is* generic anonymous function that returns TypedPropertyDescriptor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like `MethodDecorator` is not a [generic type alias](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-1-6.html#generic-type-aliases), so `T` type cannot be narrowed.

```
type Foo<T> = (x: T) => T; // this one is generic
type Bar = (x: T) => T; // and this is not
```

Which make sense, since the assumptions that are made in `foo` (i.e. `descriptor.value` has a `bind` property) are not true for `MethodDecorator` in general.

Since `type` is a mere alias, we can define our own.

```
type TypedMethodDecorator = <T extends Function>(
    target: Object,
    propertyKey: string | symbol,
    descriptor: TypedPropertyDescriptor<T>
) => TypedPropertyDescriptor<T> | void;

const foo: TypedMethodDecorator = function (target, propertyKey, descriptor) {
    return {
        configurable: true,
        enumerable: false,
        value: descriptor.value!.bind(null)
    };
}

class C {
    @foo
    m() {
        console.log('this:', this);
    }
}

new C().m(); // 'this: null'
```

Due to type inference the compiler understands that `foo` is a valid decorator.